# Mobile Redirect & Full Site Links

Tags: php, javascript, html, redirect, mobile

I'd like to redirect Android & iOS users to mobile pages specific to that audience. I've successfully been able to with the below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') != -1)) {
    document.location = "http://www.example.com/ios";
} // ]]></script>


<script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1) ) {
    document.location = "http://www.example.com/android";
} // ]]></script>
```

The only issue is, I also have "View Full Site" links on both sites that just keep looping you back. I need some kind of way to use the above code, but allow them to view the full site if they click on the link. Solutions I saw was to use a cookie, but I don't know a nice way to do so.

The last issue is, I also only want this code to apply to the index of the site. If someone comes in on an interior page, the mobile redirect should not trigger.

I've seen solutions for all three issues separately, but nothing that combines all the needs in one nice way to do so.

Thanks.

Comment: This approach is bound to fail (think of windows phones, blackberries, etc.). You should look into responsive design.

Comment: Please note, this is not my solution for a mobile site. We are offering a special deal to Android & iOS users only, so it's essentially a splash page we want to show.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle this serverside and use sessions and cookies. 
Or you can set a js cookie at first place. When the user clicks on the link to change the site "format" , change the cookie value.then if the cookie does exist , let the cookie value decide which format to display. if it doesnt check the user agent.